# Fortran - find loc method - implicit type

Tags: fortran, gfortran

I am learning fortran and need my program to find specific values in an array. A simple program like below:

```
program hello

implicit none
integer :: x
x = findloc([4,9,0,2,-9,9,1],9)

end program hello
```

is giving me the following error:

```
Error: Function 'findloc' at (1) has no IMPLICIT type
```

I am compiling it using gfortran on macbook. Will really appreciate if I can get some help regarding findloc

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The standard intrinsic `findloc` was introduced to Fortran in the 2008 revision. Support for this function first appeared in gfortran [release 9.0](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/Fortran2008Status).

The error message you see is an indication that the intrinsic is not supported in the version you are using.

You could attempt to use the required version, but at the moment this is still in development.

Fortunately, it is simple enough to loop over the elements of your array, effectively creating your own version of `findloc`.

Answer (score 0):

You have two bugs. Modifying your code slightly makes it work:

```
program hello

  implicit none
  intrinsic :: findloc
  integer :: x(1)

  x = findloc([4,9,0,2,-9,9,1], value = 9)


end program hello
```

Comment: This will only work when the compiler does provide the intrinsic. The `intrinsic` statement is not normally needed. However, it will not help if the compiler does not provide the intrinsic function. The keyword argument `value=` is not necessary either.

Comment: The array nature of `x` being required is a useful thing to point out (it isn't the problem the asker is facing, but it still important), but I suggest making it much clearer, and/or using `dim=` which may be closer to what is desired.

Answer (score 0):

Most people will want to use the `DIM=1` option with **findloc** for one dimension arrays -- otherwise the result is an array.

```
program test1
    implicit none
    integer :: arr(7) = (/4,9,0,2,-9,9,1/)
    integer :: i

    i = findloc(arr,9,dim=1)
    print '(2g0)', 'index=', i

    i = findloc(arr,9,dim=1,back=.true.)
    print '(2g0)', 'index=', i
endprogram
```

Produces this output -- one for the forward search, and one for the backward search:

```
index=2
index=6
```

As noted above, a compiler compatible with the Fortran 2008 revision is required.